# Loop Array Json with two elements from Jquery in ajax - Solved

Tags: jquery, json, loops

I have one Json is back from ajax, the json is:

```
[{"id_caracteristica":"1","nombre":"Talla"},{"id_caracteristica":"2","nombre":"Color"}]
```

I need to save in two select the following information, id select is id_caracteristica value (1), and class select is name value (Talla)

```
1ºSelect id="1" class="Talla"
2ºSelect id="2" class="Color"
```

Solved, thanks to Gagan Deep, I put an alert as proof

```
...    
dataType: "json",
success: function(data){
  $.each(data, function(i, value) {
     alert(value.id_caracteristica+" "+value.nombre);
  }
...
```

Comment: why passing `data[0]` to the each function. just pass `data` instead and check `value.id_caracteristica` and `value.nombre`

Comment: Because I did not know how to do it correctly.

And the answer you have given is completely correct and does exactly what I wanted, thank you very much.

Comment: Excellent work. I will post the comment as answer for future visitors. You may accept the answer if you like. You know reputation points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please pass `data` instead of `data[0]` to the `$.each` function. like below.

```
$.each(data, function(i, value) {
 alert(value.id_caracteristica+" "+value.nombre);
 }
```